# Printing name as first name and last name format

Tags: regex, python-3.x, spacy, data-extraction

I have a text file which contains data as:

```
Last name, First name in some of the cases
```

For e.g.:

```
The patient was referred by Dr. Douglas, John, updated by: ‎Acosta, Christina
The patient was referred by Potter, Rob,M.D.
Sam was referred by Dr. Alisa Russo
```

I want output as:

```
John Douglas
Rob Potter
Alisa Russo
```

I am using code as:

```
print(str(string.partition(',')[2].split()[0] +" "+string.partition(',')[0].split()[0]))
```

Comment: I don't think you can expect that a regex will be able to provide you what you want given the extreme variability in the string.

Comment: Why not print Acosta, Cgristina

Comment: We want only the doctors who have referred

Answer (score 1):

You can first find the names, either preceded by "Dr." or followed by "M.D.", and then when output the names, if there's a comma, swap the order of the names:

```
import re
data = '''The patient was referred by Dr. Douglas, John, updated by: ‎Acosta, Christina
The patient was referred by Potter, Rob,M.D.
Sam was referred by Dr. Alisa Russo'''
for name in re.findall(r"(?<=Dr. ){0}|{0}(?=,\s*M.D.)".format("[a-z'-]+,? [a-z'-]+"), data, re.IGNORECASE):
    print(' '.join(name.split(', ')[::-1]) if ', ' in name else name)
```

This outputs:

```
John Douglas
Rob Potter
Alisa Russo
```

Comment: this solution is good but getting wrong when the doctor has a middle name

Comment: There's no middle name in the sample input in your question. With a possible middle name, there is no way to tell a 3-word name from a 2-word name with another regular word. For example, how do you know if "Hello John Doe, M.D." refers to someone named "Hello John Doe" or simply a regular word "Hello" followed by someone named "John Doe"? You have to define a clear logic first before there can be an implementation.

Comment: Ya, I got your point. Your solution is very helpful, so I am using your logic and spacy to do so

Comment: may I know how I can convert 


Acosta, Christina, M.D. is a heart doctor

to

Christina Acosta, M.D. is a heart doctor

Comment: I now see that your new question is about replacement rather than simply finding the names. I'm going to answer this in your new question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51644998/extracting-name-as-first-name-last-name-in-python

Comment: Yes because using just Python would be little specific. The data could change in the future with some new format, so I am trying to use NLTK or SPACY so that the code becomes general and can fetch names regardless of what format it is in

Answer (score 1):

The first challenge is to capture the first and last name of the Doctors. This is hard since some names are hairy. A regex with some alternations can help, e.g.

```
(?:Dr. )(\w+) (\w+)|(?:Dr. )(\w+), (\w+)|(\w+), (\w+),?(?: ?M\.?D\.?)
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/uei82N/1)

[**Code Sample**](https://ideone.com/0dPBaH):

```
import re

regex = r"(?:Dr. )(\w+) (\w+)|(?:Dr. )(\w+), (\w+)|(\w+), (\w+),?(?: ?M\.?D\.?)"

test_str = ("The patient was referred by Dr. Douglas, John, updated by: ‎Acosta, Christina\n"
    "The patient was referred by Potter, Rob,M.D.\n"
    "Sam was referred by Dr. Alisa Russo")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)
results = []

for match in matches:
    if match.group(1):
        results.append([match.group(1), match.group(2)])
        next
    if match.group(3):
        results.append([match.group(4), match.group(3)])            
        next
    if match.group(5):
        results.append([match.group(6), match.group(5)])
        next
```

The output is a list of lists. Then, printing becomes very easy.

```
[['John', 'Douglas'], ['Rob', 'Potter'], ['Alisa', 'Russo']]
```

Comment: this solution is good but getting wrong when the doctor has a middle name

Comment: @Slickmind Yea, as I said, capturing names is hard, plus you did not mention middle names before. Here is a pattern that matches an [optional middle initial](https://regex101.com/r/uei82N/2). If this still does not fit your needs, please update your question or post a new one.

Answer (score 0):

I would honestly start by grabbing the names firstly. Use a regular expression... Once you get that, then switch up the first/last names based on the ','. Don't do it all at once.