# Extracting name as first name last name in python

Tags: regex, python-3.x, spacy, data-extraction

I have a text file with lines as:

```
Acosta, Christina, M.D. is a heart doctor

Alissa Russo, M.D. is a heart doctor
```

is there a way to convert below line:

```
Acosta, Christina, M.D. is a heart doctor
```

to

```
Christina Acosta, M.D. is a heart doctor
```

Expected Output:

```
Christina Acosta, M.D. is a heart doctor
Alissa Russo, M.D. is a heart doctor
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the follow regex to group the first and last names and substitute them in reverse order without the comma:

```
import re
data = '''Acosta, Christina, M.D. is a heart doctor
Alissa Russo, M.D. is a heart doctor'''
print(re.sub(r"([a-z'-]+), ([a-z'-]+)(?=,\s*M.D.)", r'\2 \1', data, flags=re.IGNORECASE))
```

This outputs:

```
Christina Acosta, M.D. is a heart doctor
Alissa Russo, M.D. is a heart doctor
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: A small correction, just replace M.D. with . because the format is not same everytime in the data which I have
print(re.sub(r"([a-z'-]+), ([a-z'-]+)(?=,\s*.)", r'\2 \1', data, flags=re.IGNORECASE))

Answer (score 0):

```
testline = 'Acosta, Christina, M.D. is a heart doctor'
a = testline.split(',', 1)
b = a[1].split(',',1)
newstring = b[0]+' '+a[0]+','+ b[1]
print newstring
```

your output should be: `Christina Acosta, M.D. is a heart doctor`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import re
pattern = "(\w+), (\w+), M.D. is a heart doctor"
my_string = "Acosta, Christina, M.D. is a heart doctor"
re.sub(pattern, r"\2 \1, M.D. is a heart doctor", my_string)
```

In the pattern we specify two groups, and then we use them in the substituting by referencing them with `\1` and `\2`

Comment: it will fail if it would be "Acosta, Christina, PT is a heart doctor". I appreciate the help. Thanks